# Hibernate search bounding box search

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm using [Hibernate Search 5](https://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/) to implement a full text service implementation with Apache Lucene. I'm able to get the text search working by following the steps in [this site](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-search).

Now I need to add a geo location(lat/lon) fields in the entity and referring to this [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.2/reference/en-US/html/spatial.html), it seems hibernate allows defining one using `@Latitude` & `@Longitude` annotation.

My requirement is to find all entities that matches a given keyword and falls within bounding geo polygon(given a top left corner point and bottom right corner point of the bounding box).

Referring further in the hibernate documentation, I found support for finding entities within a specific distance(more like a bounding circle) as below

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = builder
  .spatial()
  .within( radius, Unit.KM )
    .ofLatitude( centerLatitude )
    .andLongitude( centerLongitude )
  .createQuery();
```

Is there a way to do search by bounding polygon instead of radius ?

As a workaround, I can give a radius large enough to bound my box however i'll end up doing over fetching the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for bounding box queries in Hibernate Search 5.

There is such support in Hibernate Search 6: see [this part of the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-spatial-within). Hibernate Search 6 is currently in Beta and the API is different from Hibernate Search 5.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it too but would like to avoid using a beta version. I would happily take it if it becomes GA.